# Поиск клеток в радиусе от заданной

Tags: php, оптимизация

Вход - X,Y,R. Соответственно, координаты центра и радиус.
Надо найти все, что внутри круга с такими параметрами.

Есть большое подозрение на быдлокод:

```
function getCellsByRadius($x,$y,$r){
    for($i=floor($y-$r);$i<=ceil($y+$r);$i++){//высота квадрата со стороной 2r. Искомый круг точно не больше.
      for($j=floor($x-$r);$j<=ceil($x+$r);$j++){//ширина квадрата со стороной 2r
        $distance = sqrt(pow(($j - $x),2)+pow(($i - $y),2));//расстояние до каждой точки квадрата
        if($distance<$r){
          $this->cells[$j][$i]='#999';
        }
      }
    }
    $this->cells[$x][$y]='#f00';
  }
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разбыдлокодить. =(

P.S. можно проверять расстояние до точек, которые внутри квадрата +-r, но все ромба

```
x+r,y
x-r,y
x,y+r
x,y-r
```

Но мне кажется, что лишняя проверка этого ромба может только усугубить ситуацию.

Еще можно проверять только для четверти, а потом размножать на весь круг. Но опять же, поворот может дорого обойтись.

Comment: а что вам конкретно не нравится? ну, цвета неплохо бы передавать в параметрах, и последняя строчка выглядит странно. и квадратный корень считается на каждую точку, а можно всего лишь раз на строку. но результат этот код должен давать, по видимому, правильный, несмотря на неоптимальность. (disclaimer -- я не знаток php)

Comment: Вот мне и нужно оптимизация. Что результат правильный - я знаю. Последняя строка - это отмечается центр.
Как квадратный корень считать один раз на строку?! Мы же проверяем расстояние до каждой точки!

Comment: @knes: ну, например как в ответе ниже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getCellsByRadius($x,$y,$r,$ccircle,$ccenter){
    $r2 = $r * $r;
    for($i=floor($y-$r);$i<=ceil($y+$r);$i++){
      $dxmax2 = $r2 - ($y - $i) * ($y - $i);
      if ($dxmax2 < 0) continue;
      $dxmax = sqrt($dxmax2);
      $lower = floor($x-$dxmax); $upper = ceil($x+$dxmax);
      for($j=$lower;$j<=$upper;$j++){
          $this->cells[$j][$i]=$ccircle;
      }
    }
    $this->cells[$x][$y]=$ccenter;
  }
```

(Не уверен, что код правильный, я не знаток php. Может, где-то надо объявить локальные переменные.)

Comment: Во, кстати да, мы же на строке уже можем легко вычислить какой максимальный будет разброс. Отлично. =)

Comment: @knes: спасибо!

Comment: Так это я должен спасибо говорить... Спасибо. =)

Answer (score 1):

чисто спортивный интерес.  Решил просто матрицу заполнить 1, если в окружности

сделал вот так

```
$x=50;
$y=25;
$r=10;
//грубо говоря тело вашей функции
for ($i=-$r;$i<=$r;$i++)
{
$y1=ceil(sqrt(pow($r,2)-pow($i,2)));
$cells[$x+$i]=array_fill($y-$y1,2*$y1+1,1);
}
```

вывел во так тут просто решил глянуть будет ли похоже на окружность

```
for ($i=-$r;$i<=$r;$i++)
{
    for ($j=-$r;$j<=$r;$j++)
    {
    if (array_key_exists($j+$y,$cells[$x+$i]))
        { 
            echo $cells[$x+$i][$y+$j];
        }
        else
        {
            echo'0';
        }
    }
echo '<br>';
}
```

результат

```
000000000010000000000
000001111111111100000
000011111111111110000
001111111111111111100
001111111111111111100
011111111111111111110
111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111
011111111111111111110
001111111111111111100
001111111111111111100
000011111111111110000
000001111111111100000
000000000010000000000
```

Возможно гдето с округлением напутал, попробуйте. Единственное отличие что я присваиваю 1, а вы цвет ячейки. Единтсвееное что в коде нет - это присваивание цвета точки центра))) тут как говорится проще не сделаешь

Вот непонятливый. Сам же в коде делал целые числа, зная что дроби не могут быть.
Тогда как ты заставишь компьютер покрасить точку центра с координатами не являющимися целыми? Куда ты в своей окржности вписанной в квадрат 4х4 поставишь центр и покрасишь его другим цветом?ПО твоей логике он будет находится между пикселей что-ли?

Comment: результат выглядит правильно; ваш код, однако, на обрабатывает случай нецелых координат.

Comment: всмысле? а ваш код тоже не работает с дробными координатми. Да и в конечном счете коодрдинаты как никрути будут всегда целыми)

Comment: @Ale_x: работает -- для этого там `ceil` и `floor`. Они как раз на случай, если координаты центра и/или радиус не целые. Координаты высчитанных точек, конечно, целые. И из-за этого я не смог соптимизировать: не считать нижнюю половину, а брать соответствующую строку из верхней.

Comment: так и у меня ceil используется) у вас постоение элементов массива сделано ручками через цикл, у меня с помощью встроенной функции. Я просто вычисляю диапазон Y ограниченный целыми числами котороый при данной координате X будет принадлежать всегда окрудности, и запалняю его без лишних проверок и циклов)

Comment: По поводу координаты центра нецелые - если не испольуется масштаб - а грубо говоря шаг по оси равен одной точке - меньше компьютер вам не нарисует, то что будут значить дробные координаты? - они опять же будут при отрисовке переводится в целое) (Вспоминаю Pascal с рисованием графиков и работа с изображениями).

Comment: @Ale_x: ну например, вы хотите вот такой круг:

> 0110
1111
1111
0110

Тогда ваш центр должен находиться в точке (1.5, 1.5)

Comment: так я те и говорю что координата ДОЛЖНЫ БЫТЬ ЦЕЛЫМИ!!!
А как ты мне нарисуеешь такую окружность? фунцкии раюоты с графикой ОПЕРИРУЮТ ТОЛЬКО ЦЕЛЫМИ КООРДИНАТАМИ. не сможешь ты на монике поставить точку (1.5, 1.5)

Comment: Ну, смотрите. Координаты единичных пикселей, конечно, целые. а вот координаты центра и радиус -- необязательно. Примеры:

    010 0110 00100 001100
    111 1111 01110 011110
    010 1111 11111 111111
        0110 01110 111111
             00100 011110
                   001100

Координаты центров и радиусы соответственно:

1. r = 1, c = (1, 1)
2. r = 1.5, c = (1.5, 1.5)
3. r = 2, c = (2, 2)
4. r = 2.5, c = (2.5, 2.5)

Видите? Без нецелых координат не обойтись, вы не сможете нарисовать окружности 2 и 4 без этого.