# Поиск точек для многомерной сферы

Tags: математика, алгоритм, php

Можно ли расширить [данную задачу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/167064/php-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9) до N-мерного случая?

Даже так: является ли использование рекурсии и переменного числа аргументов здесь оправданным?

что-то типа

```
function get_dimension($point,$radius,$dimension_axis){
  for($i=floor($point[$dimension_axis]-$radius);$i<=ceil($point[$dimension_axis]+$r);$i++){
  if($dimension_axis>count($point)){
    //Операции с мегамерным массивом
  }else{
    get_dimension($point,$radius,++$dimension_axis);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее, обобщить легко, и рекурсия (по количеству измерений) мне кажется подходящим инструментом.

Я бы сделал как-то так (не тестировал и на псевдокоде, извините, не спец по php):

```
process_points(int currdim, point currpoint, point center, double radius)
{
    var r2 = radius * radius;
    var currpointR2 = 0;
    for (var dim = 0; dim < currdim - 1; dim++)
        currpointR2 += (currpoint[dim] - center[dim]) *
                       (currpoint[dim] - center[dim]);
    var restR2 = r2 - currpointR2;
    if (restR2 < 0) return;
    var restR = sqrt(restR2);
    var min = floor(center[currdim] - restR);
    var max = ceil(center[currdim] + restR);
    for (var xx = min; xx <= max; xx++)
    {
        point newCurrPoint = currpoint;
        newCurrPoint[dim] = xx;
        if (currdim < totaldims - 1)
            process_points(currdim + 1, newCurrPoint, center, radius);
        else // last dim
            paint_point(newCurrPoint);
    }
}

process_points(0, center, center, r);
```